# I want to set ivar using -> operator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ivar

I want to set ivar using -> operator. I got an error: Interface type cannot be statically allocated. I don't want dot operator.

```
 @interface Dream : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isBeer;

 @end
```

Class ViewController

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

  Dream dr1;
  (&dr1)->isBear = YES;
 }
```

Comment: I haven't used -> operator for a long time. I forgot some aspects. Now I'm trying to refresh my knowledge about this operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the instance variable public:

```
@interface Dream : NSObject
{
@public
    BOOL isBeer;
}
@end
```

Class ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Dream *dr1 = [[Dream alloc] init];
    dr1->isBeer = YES;
}
```

Comment: The produced error actually lies in the `Dream dr1;` line, you can't make an objective-C object on the stack.

Comment: @joerick Huh?  I think you wanted to comment on the question?

Comment: You corrected two errors in your answer- one was the visibility of the ivar, but you also corrected the object declaration... the object declaration was causing the _Interface type cannot be statically allocated_ error, I was just pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the ' * ' in the declaration:

```
Dream *dr1;
```

That is the cause of the compiler error.

In Objective-C, objects are referenced by pointers only, much like C++ instances created with new().

Also note for Objective-C objects, the distinction between '->'(arrow) and '.'(dot) is **not** the same as for C++ objects/C structs. In C/C++, you use the dot to access members of a stack variable, e.g.:

```
// Stack
MyClass myObject;
myObject.memeber = 1; 

MyStruct info;
info.member = 1;


// Heap
MyClass* pMyObject = new MyClass();
myObject->memeber = 1; 

MyStruct* pInfo = (MyStruct*) malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
pInfo->member = 1;
```

whereas in Objective-C, all objects are heap (referred to by pointers only), so you can only access members with the arrow.

The dot, on the other hand, has the **different meaning** of calling the getter/setter for a property, that **might be backed by an ivar or not.** (depends on internals)

Comment: or as joerick said, you can only create objects on the heap, not the stack.

Comment: Accessing unitialized objects on the heap; Twice the fun as on the stack!